# Where can I find a flash file uploader that doesn't require javascript?

Tags: flash, uploader

I'm looking for a flash uploader that doesn't need javascript/jquery. I'm not familiar at all with javascript so my attempts at flash/js hybrid uploaders have all failed to integrate with my script.

Answer (score 1):

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/creating-a-reusable-flash-uploader-with-actionscript-3-0-and-php/